# Constructor car calculator program

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program with the instructions below. The program does work currently, but it does not fully meet the specs.

I think I'm very close, but I'm having trouble understanding the constructor setup and how to do the current year.

### Coding Instructions

> Create a class called Car.
>
> This class should have 3 member variables:
>
> - a string called Make
> - a string called Model
> - an integer called Year
> - The class should have a function that returns the age of the car by subtracting the member variable "year" from the current year (2021).
> - The class should have a constructor that takes 3 parameters: make, model, year.

This is my code:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Historic Car Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the make of your car");
        var _Make = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the model of your car.");
        var _Model = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year your car was made.");
        int _Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Your " + _Make + " " + _Model+ " is " + (2021 - _Year) + " years old");  

    }
    
    public class Car
    {
        public string Make;
        public string Model;
        public int Year;
        public int currentYear;
        
        //Overloaded Constructor
        public Car(string _Make, string _Model, int _Year)
        {
            Make = _Make;
            Model = _Model;
            Year = _Year;   
        }
        public void display()
        {
            var Car = new Car(Make, Model, Year);
        }

        public void CarAge(int Year)
        {
            this.currentYear = 2021 - this.Year;
        }
                
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should not simply paste the specs and ask for people to complete it. Be more specific, what does not work, exactly? You also should edit your title to summarize the exact problem. I also embedded your code, please do not post links, unless you want to redirect people to an article for more information.

Comment: Hint - don't hardcode 2021. https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+get+current+year

Comment: `Car myCar = new Car("Honda", "Accord", 2020);` . Now, *that* uses the constructor you made.

Answer (score 2):

1.You need to declare those 3 member variables as `private`, if they are public it can be accessed (for both getting and setting values), and that's what we don't want. In your case constructor should be the only means of setting their values:

```
 private string Make;
 private string Model;
 private int Year;
```

2.There is no need for an extra variable, you can just return the car age directly:

```
public int GetCarAge()
{
  return 2021 - Year;
}
```

3.The Display method creates another instance of the car class, which is wrong. you may want to return some string value about current car, or something like that:

```
public string display()
{
    return "Make: " + Make + ", Model: " + Model + ", Year:" + Year.ToString();
    //return $"Make: {Make}, Model:{Model}, Year:{Year}"; //can be written like this too
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a class, but you are not using it. Lets make it a bit more meaningfull, construct an instance of a car and use it for writing:

```
public class Car
{
    public readonly string Make;
    public readonly string Model;
    public readonly int Year;

    public Car(string make, string model, int year)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
    }
  
    public int CarAge()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - Year;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Historic Car Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the make of your car");
    var make = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the model of your car.");
    var model = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year your car was made.");
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    var car = new Car(make, model, year);

    Console.WriteLine("Your " + car.Make + " " + car.Model + " is " + car.CarAge() + " years old");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a variable for `currentYear` which is not needed. The current year isn't information that relates to the car. Also your function needs to return a value. So look at the sample code below for inspiration.

```
public class Car
{
    // private fields
    string make;
    string model;
    int year;
    
    //Overloaded Constructor
    public Car(string make, string model, int year)
    {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;   
    }
    // public properties
    public string Make { get { return make; } }
    public string Model { get { return model; } }
    public int Year { get { return year; } }

    // function to calculate age
    public int CarAge(int currentYear)
    {
        return currentYear - year;
    }

    // convert class to string for dsplay
    public string ToString()
    {
        return $"{year} {make} {model} is {CarAge(DateTime.Now.Year))} years old.";
    }                
}
```

Additional functionality I included below by overriding `ToString()` which allows you to write things like `Console.WriteLine(car)` and it will display the specific information about the car. This method tells the computer how to convert the data in a class to a string representation for display or processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that `Program` and `Car` are two separate classes, even though you have declared `Car` inside the `Program` class.

In your *static* `Main` method, you need to *instantiate* (create) an *instance* (object) of the `Car` class with the parameters captured from your calls to `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Historic Car Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the make of your car");
    var make = Console.ReadLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the model of your car.");
    var model = Console.ReadLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year your car was made.");
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Create a Car Object using the above parameters:
    // This is the proof that:
    //    The class should have a constructor that takes 3 parameters: make, model, year.
    Car car = new Car(make, model, year);

    // Deliberately demonstrate you have an Age function by
    // calling the Age function on the car:
    Console.WriteLine("Your car's age is {0} years old", car.Age());  

    // Override standard Object.ToString() to create a string representation
    // Instead of creating a new method called display().
    Console.WriteLine("Your Car: {0}", car);
}
```

You should should get into the habit of using *Properties* to represent the meta-data of the car, the following code will use the auto-properties syntax to declare these properties as readonly:

```
    public string Make { get; }
    public string Model { get; }
    public int Year { get; }
```

> remove currentYear... that is not needed at all.

There is a comment about an overloaded constructor... But you have not overloaded anything. At the very least you should remove that comment.

> If your class needs to support serilization, then it will be important to create an additional *default* constructor that takes no parameters, but then the backing properties will also need to be settable from external contexts. Serilization is an important consideration for all classes in modern programming as we commonly use serilization techniques to transfer data between APIs and files, in a real world application you would want your Car instance to be saved to a database or disk, a user does not re-enter their car details, for every car, every time they use your app. This is where serialization becomes very useful, I'll include an example of this at the end of this post.

4 things about your `CarAge` function:

1. You are not using the value of `Year` argument at all, so remove it.
2. The name is redundant, we already know it is a *Car* `Car.CarAge()` is just a silly, make your code easier to read by renaming to something that includes a verb to describe what it does like `CalculateAge()` or perhaps just simply `Age()`.
3. You do not need to create a new instance of a `Car`, this method is already part of a car definition, so it has access to the member variables.
4. This is contraversial... at least from a homework point of view, the value of `2021` should NOT be hardcoded, even though the requirement suggests this. In real world software design hardcoding *time*, *system* or *environment* based variables is a serious red flag

- In .NET `DateTime.Now` will give you the current time and date, from there you can access the current year.

  ```
  public int Age()
  {
      return DateTime.Now.Year - this.Year;
  }
  ```

Finally, replace your `display` method with an *override* of the standard `Object.ToString()`. That is the whole purpose of the `ToString()` to create the standard *display* representation of your class.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Make: {0}, Model: {1}, Year: {2}, Age: {3}", this.Make, this.Model, this.Year, this.Age();
        // You could also use string interpolation:
        // return $"Make: {this.Make}, Model: {this.Model}, Year: {this.Year}, Age: {this.Age()}";
    }
```

Overall this makes your Car class look something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; }
    public string Model { get; }
    public int Year { get; }
    

    public Car(string make, string model, int year)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;   
    }

    /// <summary>Override ToString to return the standard display format for a car</summary>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Make: {0}, Model: {1}, Year: {2}, Age: {3}", this.Make, this.Model, this.Year, this.Age();
        // You could also use string interpolation:
        // return $"Make: {this.Make}, Model: {this.Model}, Year: {this.Year}, Age: {this.Age()}";
    }

    /// <summary>Caculate and return the Current Age of this Car based on the current System Year and stamp Year of this car.</summary>
    public int Age()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - this.Year;
    }
            
}
```

---

#### Serialization Support

As explained above, if is a good habit to get into supporting serialization, this will enable the instances of your class to be saved to text based files or to be transferred via text based protocols like HTTP. In an increasingly *cloud* oriented industry, you will come across this requirement very soon.

To support Serialization in a generic sense a class needs to have the following:

1. A parameter-less constructor, this is known as the *default* constructor.
2. The meta-data that you want to be saved and restored MUST be declared as `public` *Properties*.

This is because the default string based serialization processors will create an instance of the target class using the default constructor and will then set each of the properties one by one.

We can add the default serialization support to your `Car` class by making the auto-properties settable by external contexts and by adding the default constructor:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get;set; }
    public string Model { get;set; }
    public int Year { get;set; }
    
    /// <summary>Create a default Car representation, meta-data will need to be set explicitly </summary>
    public Car()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>Overload to Create a Car Instance with the specified meta-data</summary>
    public Car(string make, string model, int year)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;   
    }

    /// <summary>Override ToString to return the standard display format for a car</summary>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Make: {0}, Model: {1}, Year: {2}, Age: {3}", this.Make, this.Model, this.Year, this.Age();
        // You could also use string interpolation:
        // return $"Make: {this.Make}, Model: {this.Model}, Year: {this.Year}, Age: {this.Age()}";
    }

    /// <summary>Caculate and return the Current Age of this Car based on the current System Year and stamp Year of this car.</summary>
    public int Age()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - this.Year;
    }                
}
```

There are other benefits to this Serialization ready implementation, we can now avoid overloaded constructors altogether with the following class instantiation syntax:

```
var car = new Car { Make = make, Model = model, Year = year };
```

Comment: You can not return from function with void. It is also debatable, if Property is member variable as required by the instructions.

Comment: Thanks @AntonínLejsek my mistake for trying to code in the browser ;) Regardless of the instructions, those are obvious candidates for public accessible properties, especially given the serialization scenario that I have outlined. We need to be careful in public forums to offer sound advice that benefits the community, I challenge anyone to argue a scenario where those properties should not be public. I agree they could theoretically be public readonly, however the argument for serialization is too strong to disregard. If we're going to learn, lets do it properly.